# How to add vertical scrollbar to dojox.grid.DataGrid?

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

How to add vertical scrollbar to dojox.grid.DataGrid ?

```
<div id="system_status" >
                    <div dojoType="dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore" jsId="system_flags"    data="window.store_data_system_flags"> </div> 
                    <div id="grid"  dojoType="dojox.grid.DataGrid" store="system_flags"   structure="window.layout_system_flags" queryOptions="{deep:true}" query="{}" clientSort="true" rowsPerPage="10"> </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: The vertical scrollbar should appear if you use CSS to control the size of the enclosing HTML element correctly, the ``div`` in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set CSS "height" style for div with id "system_status" and if the grid will need more space than scrollbar will appear automatically.

```
<div id="system_status" style="height:200px" >
                    <div dojoType="dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore" jsId="system_flags"    data="window.store_data_system_flags"> </div> 
                    <div id="grid"  dojoType="dojox.grid.DataGrid" store="system_flags"   structure="window.layout_system_flags" queryOptions="{deep:true}" query="{}" clientSort="true" rowsPerPage="10"> </div>
                </div>
```

[dojo-grid-styling](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojox/grid/DataGrid#grid-styling-rows)

Answer (score 0):

I found I could add this style to override the dojo style that might cut off anything at the bottom of the grid:

```
.dojoxGridContent {
    overflow: auto;
}
```